# C# Emacs mode questions - indentation and build

Tags: c#, emacs, mono

I installed [emacs C# mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CSharpMode).

The .emacs file is as follows

```
(require 'csharp-mode)
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (append '(("\\.cs$" . csharp-mode)) auto-mode-alist))
(defun my-csharp-mode-fn ()
  "function that runs when csharp-mode is initialized for a buffer."
  (setq default-tab-width 4)
)
(add-hook  'csharp-mode-hook 'my-csharp-mode-fn t)
```

It works pretty fine, but I see the block ({..}) is aligned what I intended. I mean, in some cases I have this.

```
private static int StringCompare(string x, string y)
{
  int result;
  if (x == null)
    {

    }
}
```

when I expect this

```
private static int StringCompare(string x, string y)
{
  int result;
  if (x == null)
  {

  }
}
```

Together with this, I always have 2 indentation for the code, but I want it to be 4.

My questions are

- How can I control the indentation in C# emacs mode?
- How can I control the '{' and '}' to have the  same indentation as it's previous code.
- Does C# mode provide compilation to generate exe/dll file within the editor with commands?

I use emacs C# mode on Mac OS X/mono.

### ADDED

I found that C# mode can also use C mode, so M-x c-set-style works, and awk style just works for me. The problem is that I have to turn on awk mode whenever I use c mode. Is there a way to run "M-x c-set-style and awk" mode automatically with c mode?

Comment: to answer your question about compiling - yes. Just use M-x compile. You need to set your compile command appropriately (msbuild, nmake, csc.exe, whatever).  csharpmode is also integrated for use with flymake. There is documentation in the csharpmode elisp code describing how this integration works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add these lines to your `my-csharp-mode-fn`:

```
; Set indentation level to 4 spaces (instead of 2)
(setq c-basic-offset 4)
; Set the extra indentation before a substatement (e.g. the opening brace in
; the consequent block of an if statement) to 0 (instead of '+)
(c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0)
```

Alternatively, you can add them to your common C mode hook, which runs for all C mode-related modes: C, C++, Objective-C, Java, C#, and more:

```
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)
  (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

See the [CC mode documentation](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/cc-mode/cc-mode_6.html) for the nitty-gritty details on customizing indentation.

Answer (score 1):

For the indentation, you want 
(setq c-basic-offset 4)
in your hook above.

Answer (score 0):

The [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3956173/1497596) given by @Adam Rosenfeld here for making the changes to your `.emacs` file can also be implemented via the easy customization interface provided by Emacs.

To set `c-basic-offset` to `4`:

```
M-x customize-option RET c-basic-offset RET
```

To set `substatement-open` to `0`:

```
M-x customize-option RET c-offsets-alist RET
```

The easy customization interface provided by Emacs will add these settings to your `.emacs` file for you.

Note that these changes will affect all C mode-related modes. So if this is not what you want, please see Adam's advice for including the appropriate additions to `csharp-mode-hook`.